# Why am I getting 'google is not defined' when asynchronously loading Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading Google Maps asynchronously, but it seems my code is executed before Goole Maps is loaded.

```
Brand.init();

var Brand = {
  stores: [],

  init: function(){
    // Load Google Maps with callback
    GoogleMaps.loadGoogleMapScript(Brand.setMarkers());

  },

  setMarkers: {
    GoogleMaps.setMarkers(stores);
  }
}

var GoogleMaps = {
    loadGoogleMapScript: function(callback) {

        if (typeof google === 'undefined') {

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=' + callback + '&key=' + config.googleApiKey;
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        } else {
            callback;
        }
    },

    setMarkers: function(stores){

      if (typeof google === 'undefined') {
            console.log('GM is undefined');
            setTimeout( function () {
                GoogleMaps.setMarkers(stores);
            }, 500);
      }

      // Even if 'google' is not defined, it still executes the below code
      // and gives 'google is not defined'
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to how I can solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

`GoogleMaps.loadGoogleMapScript(Brand.setMarkers());`

Which actually calls `Brand.setMarkers`, you are not passing a reference, you are passing the returned value of the function call. I don't even know if this passes as a valid function, maybe it's part of a ES6 shorthand function declaration?:

```
setMarkers: {
    GoogleMaps.setMarkers(stores);
  }
```

If the function is called it will go all the way to the `bounds` variable declaration which will try to access `google.maps` which is not defined yet.

Also, take note that the supplied `callback` parameter for the API is a string containing the function to be called, not your usual function reference (it's being casted to string anyway when you concatenate it). Once the script tag is loaded it will call the function name supplied in this argument.

```js
function callMe(){
  $('#results').html(JSON.stringify(google.maps, null, '\t'));
  }
var string = "<script async defer src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=callMe\"></scr" + "ipt>";
$(string).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Isn't the callback called after Google Maps loader is initiated? (As descibed in the docs: http://bit.ly/1icjTl1) So once Google Maps is loaded, it calls the callback function (?)

Comment: The API `callback` parameter will call the function after the script is loaded yes. It's just a matter of how you are doing it. The callback passed to the api point must be a string that holds the function name to be called back. You don't need to call the function manually, the script will do it.

Comment: AH! You know, you could have simplified your answer by just writing: You must pass the string `GoogleMaps.loadGoogleMapScript("Brand.setMarkers");`  not the call the function ;-). Thanks

Comment: I wanted to explain your mistake and then how to fix it. Sorry if it was too long an explanation :P